# Can I use a present participle clause to express a condition?

Tags: present-participles

According to the books I have read, the present participle clauses can be used to talk about:

-Things happening at the same time as, or just before, the main action.

-Result of the action in the main clause.

-Reason of the action in the main clause.

-To give background information.

But could I use it to express a condition, like this "Opening the window, you will breathe some fresh air"?

Comment: We'd usually include the agency-marking 'by' here. Perhaps not always.

Comment: Your use of _condition_ is not clear to me. Do you mean "a state", or do you mean "a condition which has to be met"?

Comment: @ColinFine OP is asking whether "opening the window" can be interpreted as "if you open the window" (a conditional clause). I think it can, but, as Edwin Ashworth suggested in his comment, it can also indicate manner: it is by opening the window that you will breathe... I think a participial clause can express condition, as in "Studying long hours, you will most probably pass the exam".

Comment: I read *Opening the window* to mean upon opening, as in *Turning left, you will notice the ocean view.* Launching the computer application, you will reach the splash screen with login fields. Sounds fine.

Comment: The act of opening a window does not assist breathing. _With the window open, you will be able to breathe some fresh air._ The  breathing is the consequence of the existence of an opening, not the consequence of the exertion of opening. So your participle is not the condition. _Unlatching the window enables it to be opened_ however, displays a participle with a consequence.